# How do I delete a repo in artifactory?

Tags: artifactory

I'm able to delete content and versions from the web UI. I need to delete the artifact from the tree.
Cannot find any reference in Artifactory 5 User Guide as I'm using 5.8.4.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To delete a repository, Go to the "Admin" tab in the sidebar, and go to one of the links under "Repositories" (probably "Local"). From here, click the `x` on the right end of the repository you want to delete, or select the repository and click the "delete" button.

Note that you need admin privileges to do this.